# error: no matching function for call to 'std::optional<smoltcp::Buffer>::optional(smoltcp::Buffer&)'

Tags: c++, function, class, c++17, stdoptional

I am trying to make a function that returns an `std::optional` to `Buffer`:

```
std::optional<Buffer> receive(SmolSocket smolSocket)
{
   //...
   return std::optional<Buffer>(buffer);
}
```

Where `Buffer` is simply

```
struct Buffer
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data;
   size_t len = 0;
   bool empty = false;

   Buffer(CBuffer cBuffer)
   {
      data = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(cBuffer.data);
      len = cBuffer.len;
   }

   Buffer(bool empty)
   {
      data = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(nullptr);
      this->len = 0;
      this->empty = empty;
   }

   uint8_t* getData()
   {
      return data.get();
   }
};
```

But I am getting lots of errors:

```
/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/libopenvpn/../../smoltcp_cpp_interface/src/virtual_tun/interface.h:283:52: error: no matching function for call to 'std::optional<smoltcp::Buffer>::optional(smoltcp::Buffer&)'
  283 |                 return std::optional<Buffer>(buffer);

/usr/include/c++/9/optional:760:2: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_constructible<smoltcp::Buffer, _Args&& ...> >, bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::optional<_Tp>::optional(std::in_place_t, _Args&& ...)'
  760 |  optional(in_place_t, _Args&&... __args)
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:760:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:758:56: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'
  758 |         _Requires<is_constructible<_Tp, _Args&&...>> = false>

note:   'smoltcp::Buffer' is not derived from 'std::optional<_Tp>'
  283 |                 return std::optional<Buffer>(buffer);
```

I have used `std::optional` in other situations and I can not see what is the problem here.

I also tried using `return std::optional<Buffer>{buffer};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in order to do

```
std::optional<Buffer>(buffer);
```

you need a copy-or-move constructor. When you provide a parameterized constructor (i.e. `Buffer(CBuffer cBuffer)`), the compiler will not generate both of them. So you need to explicitly provide them.

However, in your case, you have one more issue. The **member `data` is non-copyable**(i.e. `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`), meaning **only move constructor is that you can provide.**

Therefore provide the move-constructor

```
struct Buffer
{
public:
   Buffer(Buffer&& rhs)
      : data{ std::move(rhs.data) }
      , len{rhs.len}
   {}
   // ... other code
};
```

and move the `buffer` in the function:

```
std::optional<Buffer> receive()
{
   // ...
   return std::optional<Buffer>(std::move(buffer));
}
```

**([See a minimal example demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Tfbcz))**

Answer (score 2):

**To be short:** You should add copy- or move-constructor to `Buffer`.

**More details:**

You have `Buffer` object and need to create another `Buffer` (in `std::optional`), but there is no constructor in `Buffer` which can accept parameters you're passing. Compiler **doesn't generate** default copy/move-constructors, because you declared custom one. So, you should construct `std::optional<Buffer>` from `bool`, from `CBuffer` or add another one with `const Buffer&` or `Buffer&&`.